# Mirth- Database writer error

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, mirth

I am trying to create a channel to write to a database from HTTP source.

I have made two destinations both to same database. One destination writes via JavaScript and the other with SQL.

The data gets written to database in the first destination(the JavaScript one) but not through the second(SQL). I am not able to get the tables through "Insert" button also. It gives the following error:

[image]

Someone please give me the solution to set up database connection without any flaw. Please note that the database is secured one in AWS instance.

Comment: Error specifies the DB connectivity details are incorrect. Your PostgreSQL is installed on a EC2 system of AWS? or like a separate DB service?. I have worked on connecting MySQL deployed on EC2. Try this link https://hl7engine.wordpress.com/2017/12/13/integrating-aws-ec2-mysql-to-mirth-engine/

Comment: @VibinGuvera Hi Vibin, Thanks for your suggestion.  Client says that they are getting the same error(shown in the image attached above), but they are able to connect to the database through Javascript.   Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to database via javascript, you will need to select "Yes" under the option to use javascript.  Then your connector will look something like this:

```
var dbConn;

try {
    dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver','ServerURL','Username','Password');

    // You may access this result below with $('column_name')
    return result;
} finally {
    if (dbConn) { 
        dbConn.close();
    }
}
```

Note that you can click on the "generate" button and this template will be created for you in the javascript window.

Based on the information you have given, I am not sure that your method/syntax is the cause to your error.  Can you verify that your database driver jar file is located in your installation?  (Mine is located at "...\Mirth Connect\server-lib\database"